# I want to run 20A constant current and 4.2V on a load using a variable DC power supply rated same

Tags: power-supply, power, battery-charging

I want to run 20A constant current and 4.2V on a load using a variable DC power supply rated as 20A, 30V. But because my power supply is a switching CC, Cv type, and it kept switching to CV at only 1.2A. I really want to run it at 20A and 4.2V (CC, CV) on the same load despite the change of resistance of the load.

I will really appreciate step by step instruction on how to achieve that, if using resistors etc. In more details, the load is a 3.75V, 1000mAh battery and this battery is designed to take this much load for only 3 minutes to recharge. Currently the battery is on the nominal voltage checked using a multimeter.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be charging that battery in a purpose built charging bag, and wearing Nomex overalls (you, not the battery) while doing so would probably do no harm.

You also want to be sure that the supply will genuinely deliver 20A at 4.2V.

Assuming that

- the battery CAN tolerate the rate you say,
- The supply is capable of safely delivering 4.2V at 20A for 3+ minutes.
- The supply current limit can not be set when not loaded.

Disconnect any load.
Set supply to say 4.25V.
Set CC control to minimum.
Short supply output terminals
Adjust CC control until I = 20A
Unshort terminals.

The supply is now ready. When loaded below 4.2V it will deliver 20A.
When Vload rises to 4.2V it will deliver 20A or less.

Connect supply to fully discharged battery with correct polarity.
After 3 minutes the battery WILL NOT be fully charged.
This is because when Vbattery rises to 4.2V the supply will go into CV mode ND current will be set by the battery. It will start to taper down.
CV to CC change over will probably happen in the 2 m to 2m 30s range.
This is a natural consequence of LiIon / LiPo chemistry.

IF you are sure that the batter will tolerate (for some values of tolerate) a constant 20A input then the charger should be set to 20A CC as above **AND** the supply voltage set "higher.
MAYBE 4.5V. Maybe 4.7 Maybe - flaming ruin .... .
This is not how the books ever say you can do it.
this violates the most fundamental principles of LiIon charging.
This sounds like fun :-)

If it works, more power to you, but battery life will be shortened so it will be less energy to you overall long term.

Comment: Many thanks Russel, this is actually not a Li-ion battery. Very different chemistry, entirely new. I will try the instructions and I promise to send you the outcome if I don't end up in the hospital.

Comment: This just sounds like a great way to end up with a big flaming pile of rubble, especially considering this is a purported 'entirely new chemistry' and OP isn't well-versed in electronics to begin with. Even though it's probably Li+ as no other worthwhile anode materials exist that charge near that redox potential. Is this one of those new-fangled lithium-ion-capacitor hybrids?

Comment: LiFePO4? LiTO? ...? I'd love to know what sort of battery it is and where you get them from.

Comment: Hello, fortunately no flames, not even heating, the dc power supply gave 20A but switched to CV and current tapered down. the battery got fully charged (4.2V) after 14 minutes instead of 3 minutes, and at 4.2V the current was 0.5A. I really need a steady 20A for 3 minutes. What do you think went wrong from my side? I actually set it to 4.2V, short the terminals and dialed the CC until I=20A. Do you think I should increase to 4.5V, 4.7V. Will really appreciate further tips.

Comment: Am currently discharging the fully charged supper battery at 0.5C. It should be safely discharged in 2 hours. Please help with DC power supply, to supply steady 20A for 3 minutes regardless of change in battery resistance. many thanks as I look forward to read from you.

Comment: Finally, I was able to run it successfully after several trials, supply was set to 4.7V and 20A was on CC for 3 minutes after which I got 4.2V on the battery, not heating, no flames. This is a new graphene tech battery with special material forming the electrodes/terminals. It took nearly 5 hour to be fully discharged at 0.5C, performance was excellent. Thanks for the tips

Comment: If you can discharge ot for 5 hours at 0.5C you are getting 5 x 0.5 = 2.5 times as much capacity as you think you have. eg you say 1000 mAh capacity. 20A x 3 minutes from discharged = 1000 mAh. 0.5C = 500 mA. 5h x 500 mA = 2500 mAh = 2.5C = something is wrong.

Comment: Not sure if my calculation was right, I discharged by shorting the terminals with a 7.5 Ohm resistor of about 2W. Discharged until Vbat = 2.8V. Is this right?